# Vim - Cursorline turns on after saving a remote file

Tags: vim, scp

Using `vim scp://....` I open a remote file.
cursorline is not shown until I save the file(:w). When I type :w and enter password, cursorline appears.If I type `:set nocursorline` it disappears but again when I type `:w` it appears.

When I edit file in remote machine cursorline is turned off and is not shown.

Why does it have such a behavior?

Comment: This looks very much like a cross-post of [SO 9608974](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608974/horizontal-line-in-vim). It is not off-topic here, but cross-posts are discouraged (see “Cross-posting” in the [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq)).